# Show loading animation when collapsible block is opening Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a problem trying to show loading icon when collapsible block is opening. I have a collapsible block with a listview inside which is populated dynamically via ajax/php. They list might have up to 500 elements, so I would like to show loading animation while it is loading.

I have tried

```
$('div.century').live('expand', function(){
 var idval = $(this).attr('id'); 
 console.log('expanded'+idval);

 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg ();
 $.get("helpers/getByCentury.php", { id: idval},
 function(data){
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data);
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").listview('refresh');
 });
 $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
});
```

I have also tried

```
$('div.century').live('expand', function(){
 var idval = $(this).attr('id'); 
 console.log('expanded'+idval);

 $.mobile.pageLoading(); 
 $.get("helpers/getByCentury.php", { id: idval},
 function(data){
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data);
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").listview('refresh');
 });
 $.mobile.pageLoading(true); 
});
```

without any luck.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()` in the callback function for your ajax call:

```
$('div.century').live('expand', function(){
 var idval = $(this).attr('id'); 
 console.log('expanded'+idval);

 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg ();
 $.get("helpers/getByCentury.php", { id: idval},
 function(data){
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data);
 $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").listview('refresh');
 $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();//NOTICE: this has been moved inside the callback function for your $.get() call
 });
});
```

Also a couple pointers.

- You are using the `$("#"+idval+" ul.ulist")` selector twice in a row, you can make that more efficient by chaining function calls together like so:

`$("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data).listview('refresh');`

- If other people view your webpage in a browser that does not have the `console.log` function they will get an error and your JS will stop running, it is normally a good idea to put calls to the `console.log` function inside a conditional that checks for the existance of that function:

`if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') {
    console.log('expanded'+idval);
}`

Comment: Jasper, once again thanks. And also thanks for the suggestions. I am a beginner at javascript and jquery. Answer like this one make me a better programmer. Thanks.